# How to arrange data fetched from mysql as per columns in html table?

Tags: php, html

I have data from mysql coming in this format (The term goes upto 9 and course could be more in a Term. The assessed column could have an empty value or single value):

| Term | Course | ASSESSED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SCIENCE-100 |  |
| 1 | STEM-200 | BC |
| 2 | ASP-400 | AB |
| 3 | LEV-100 | CD |
| 3 | WEL-200 | AB |

I want to show this table in the following table format using PHP:

| Term | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Course | SCIENCE-100 | ASP-400 (AB) | LEV-100 (CD) |
|  | STEM-200 (BC) |  | WEL-200 (AB) |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

I am using following PHP script to get desirable results but all it does is put everything into one column:

Here, semester is an array of Term, course is an array of course and level is an array of assessed.

```
$j=1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
if($semester[$i] == $semester[$j]){
echo $semester[$i];
echo $semester[$j];
echo '<td>'.$courses[$i]." ".$level[$i].'</td></tr>';
}
else
{
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$courses[$i]." ".$level[$i].'</td>';
echo'</tr>';
}
$j++;
}
```

Comment: "Using PHP" - where? In the browser?

Comment: Yeah, use PHP to display an html table with the above format

Comment: Then IMO you ask for too much. You did not provide anything you tried. Its not done in a min.

Comment: Sorry, I just made an edit where I just mentioned the logic I am trying to implement.

Comment: Did you split the rows into the 3 arrays? If yes - are they still in the same order? _If you get the data from your database like in the 1st table then you may not need to split them._

Comment: Yes, I split them into 3 and they are in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to first group the courses by terms in a 2D array: first dimension is the term, second dimension represents courses of each term

```
$groupedByTerm = [];
foreach ($courses as $course) {
    if (! isset($groupedByTerm[$course['term']])) {
        $groupedByTerm[$course['term']] = [];
    }
    $groupedByTerm[$course['term']][] = $course['course'];
}
```

So the snippet above would transform an initial array represented like this:

```
// representation of the $courses array
[
    ['term' => 1, 'course' => 'Course A'],
    ['term' => 1, 'course' => 'Course B'],
    ['term' => 2, 'course' => 'Course C'],
    ['term' => 3, 'course' => 'Course D'],
    ['term' => 3, 'course' => 'Course E'],
];
```

into this

```
// representation of the $groupedByTerm array after running the snippet
[
    1 => ['Course A', 'Course B'],
    2 => ['Course C'],
    3 => ['Course D', 'Course E'],
];
```

Then, for building a table,using the data structure above, you will loop until all the terms are empty, which can be done with a do-while that will complete when all the arrays for each terms are empty:

```
$row = 0;
$row = 0;
do {
    $hasData = false;
    echo '<tr>';
    if ($row == 0) {
        echo '<td>Course</td>';
    } else {
        echo '<td></td>';
    }
    foreach ($groupedByTerm as $term) {
        echo '<td>';
        if (is_array($term) && isset($term[$row])) {
            $hasData = true;
            echo $term[$row];
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $row++;

} while($hasData);
```

The implementation above is what would render the body of the table. I simply use echo statements but you could accumulate the string in a variable.

Comment: Can you actually show me how the groupedbyTerm would look like?

Comment: @NisargShah I have updated my example to show an example of the array as you would receive it, and the result after the grouping transformation

Comment: I tried implementing this and it kept giving me illegal string offset for course and term.

Comment: I was able to implement. Thank you. Just wanted to suggest you a change, To build that 2D array Grouped By Term, its better to implement a while loop here, as foreach loop was giving an error regarding illegal string offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to make the horizontal table into vertical table:

PHP:

```
<?php
  function create(string $prefix, string $suffix, array $array){
    $content = '';
    foreach($array as $value){
      $content .= $prefix . $value . $suffix;
    }
    return $content;
  }
  $result= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <?php echo create('<th>', '</th>', array_column($result, 'columnname1')) ?>
      <?php echo create('<td>', '</td>', array_column($result, 'columnname2')) ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me $result= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  what this line does here ?

Comment: I am assuming the $stmt is your sql query.  fetchAll will allow you to fetch all rows from a result set associated with a PDO object. PDO::FETCH_ASSOC – returns an array indexed by column name

Comment: You can also use mysql_fetch_assoc  for the same.